# From-time-to-time vs. From time to time

Tags: idioms, expressions, idiomatic-language

I used to use **from time to time** but I got recently corrected to use **from-time-to-time** (actually it's **from time-to-time** but I think both are effectively the same). It seems like **from-time-to-time** is also on a dictionary and I guess both are interchangeable, but since someone corrected my writing to the latter form, I wonder if there is a sort of idiomatic preference where one of them is preferred in some situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct. *From time to time* is the only standard version. I found the hyphenated version only in yourdictionary.com which is a wiki and is not authoritative.